# Unexpected commas in output using a 2d array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I used a class to class to organize everything I needed in this small project and made it require a 2d array to print out a field to the screen

```js
class Field {
  constructor(fieldArr) {
    this.fieldArr = fieldArr;
  }
  get field() {
    return this.print(); 
  }
  print() {
    console.log(this.fieldArr.join("\n")) // new line made after each array
  }
}

const myField = new Field([
    ["*", "░", "O"],
    ["░", "░", "░"],
    ["O", "░", "O"]
])
myField.print()
```

expected:

```
*░O
░░░
O░O
```

got:

```
*,░,O
░,░,░
O,░,O
```

Comment: You have an array of arrays. When you join the outer array, each inner array gets turned into a string. And this is what the default string representation looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working with a 2-d array, but you `join()` the outer array.

YOu should `map()` each inner item, to `join()` those (with nothing for now), and then `join()` the resulting string with a newlinE:

```js
class Field {
  constructor(fieldArr) {
    this.fieldArr = fieldArr;
  }
  get field() {
    return this.print(); 
  }
  print() {
    console.log(this.fieldArr.map(m => m.join("")).join("\n")) // new line made after each array
  }
}

const myField = new Field([
    ["*", "░", "O"],
    ["░", "░", "░"],
    ["O", "░", "O"]
])
myField.print()
```

Comment: lol, posted simultaneously :)

Comment: Haha damn, just 11 seconds between us ;)

Comment: you won, i removed my answer :)

Answer (score -1):

```html
I think, the print() method is logging each element of the arrays individually instead of joining them together.

class Field {
    constructor(fieldArr) {
      this.fieldArr = fieldArr;
    }
    
    get field() {
      return this.print();
    }
    
    print() {
      for (let row of this.fieldArr) {
        console.log(row.join("")); // concatenate elements before joining
      }
    }
  }
  
  const myField = new Field([
      ["*", "░", "O"],
      ["░", "░", "░"],
      ["O", "░", "O"]
  ]);
  
  myField.print();


Now expected result.

*░O
░░░
O░O
```